SEP-0007 for Point of sale transactions (offline)
I need  more  information  how
Can be offline  payment without  internet
. Because  I need  to use it  for offline payment . If  there  an image  describes offline  payment
Workflow  for   normal  user

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I read in the stellar documents it could be create transactions offline  in sales of point. How know if they customer have balance to pay

How  know  the transactions is  correct and  there is no manipulate  with  data  of transactions
